# Disabling "Unicode Compression" property by SQL Query ( Access )

Tags: sql, ms-access, compression

Is it possible to have a SQL statement in Microsoft Access that can disable the unicode compression property on a column ?

Something in the lines of :

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable 
ALTER COLUMN MyColumn DISABLE UNICODE COMPRESSION
```

Comment: Will you accept VBA rather than SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You simply need to omit the `WITH COMPRESSION` keywords when you call your alter statement. Thus, the following would **add** Unicode compression:

```
ALTER TABLE [Table1] ADD COLUMN Col1 TEXT(100) WITH COMPRESSION NOT NULL;
```

If after executing the above, you turned around and executed the following:

```
ALTER TABLE [Table1] ALTER COLUMN Col1 TEXT(100) NOT NULL;
```

It would remove Unicode compression.

Comment: @Remou - Sorry. Typo. It should say "ALTER COLUMN" not "ADD COLUMN". I've updated my post.

Comment: Good stuff! As an aside, this will have to be run with a connection object & VBA.

Comment: @Remou - Correct. It cannot be executed via DAO; it must use an ADO connection. In fact, can any DDL SQL can be executed via DAO? I don't think it can.

Comment: You can execute *some* DDL with DAO, but ADO offers more capabilities.  Furthermore, statements can have different results with the 2 object models.  For example, `CREATE TABLE foo (bar TEXT);`  From DAO, bar is a text field with size 255.  But with ADO, bar will be a memo field.

Comment: The different DDL support between DAO and ADO is annoying legacy of MS's ill-fated ADO-everywhere campaign from c. 2000. I would hope that sooner or later, the ACE version of DAO will be updated to include support in DDL for all features of ACE tables/fields. DAO has almost always been preferred to DDL for handling structural changes to Jet/ACE database precisely because it is much more complete than DDL (except for the things the MS intentionally crippled in the DAO/ADO wars such that ADO supports them and DAO does not; that's not about DDL, of course).